# Why does solving a derivative of sec(x) via power rule gets me a wrong value?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, trigonometry, solution-verification

I’m trying to get a derivative of $\sec(x)$ with respect to x.

The correct derivative is $\dfrac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)^2}$, though this is not match the value that I was trying to solve.

Since $\sec(x) =\dfrac{1}{ \cos(x)}, \sec(x)’ =\bigg(\dfrac{1}{\cos(x)}\bigg)’ =  \dfrac{-1}{\cos(x)^2}$

But when I applied a random value, such as $\frac{\pi}{3}$, to the equation, the first (correct) derivative gets me 3.46 while the second one gets me -4.

I wonder what I’m making a mistake on. I think the problem is I used power rule instead of quotient rule, but am not sure why power rule here gives me the wrong value. In fact, I tried to solve $x^{-1}$ using both quotient rule and power rule, both got me $\dfrac{-1}{x^2}$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to apply the chain rule: $(f(g(x))^{'}=f^{'}(g(x))\cdot g^{'}(x)$ In your case it is

$\left(\sec(x)\right)^{'} = \left(\cos^{-1}(x)\right)^{'}=-1\cdot \cos^{-2}(x)\cdot (-\sin(x))=\tan(x)\cdot \sec(x)$

Comment: Thanks! I seemed to have a mistake in not seeing `cos(x)^(-1)` as a composite function of `cos(x)` and `x^(-1)`.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can use the reciprocal rule: if $f$ is differentiable at $x$, and $f(x)\neq0$, then $1/f$ is differentiable at $x$, and
$$
\left(\frac1f\right)'\left(x\right)=-\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)^2} \, .
$$
Applying this theorem in the case $f=\cos$, we see that
$$
\sec'(x)=\left(\frac1\cos\right)'\left(x\right)=-\frac{\cos'(x)}{\cos^2(x)}=\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos^2(x)}=\frac{1}{\cos(x)}\cdot\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}=\sec(x)\tan(x) \, ,
$$
at all points where $\cos(x)\neq0$, i.e. whenever $x$ is not of the form $\pi/2+k\pi,k\in\mathbb Z$.

The reciprocal rule is a special case of the quotient rule, which states that under the appropriate conditions,
$$
\left(\frac{f}{g}\right)'=\frac{f'g-fg'}{g^2} \, .
$$